# Error Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string al intentar mostrar un valor de una consulta en una tabla php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de inventario donde tengo que mostrar en una tabla los productos con su respectivo stock y al final el total de stock de todo el almacén.

Tengo el siguiente codigo para mostrar ese total

```
$suma = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT sum(stock) FROM  principal")
  or die('Error '.mysqli_error($mysqli));

<td width='80' height='13' align='center' valign='middle'>Total</td>
                                                            <td width='80' height='13' align='center' valign='middle'></td>
<td width='80' height='13' align='center' valign='middle'></td>
<td width='80' height='13' align='center' valign='middle'><?php echo $suma; ?></td>
```

Pero al cargar la pagina me aparece el error

> "Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string"

Entiendo que es por que la variable suma no es `String`, creo que es de tipo `result` pero como podría convertirla para mostrar el total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es claro , `mysqli_query` retorna `mysqli_result` que no es posible imprimir como si fuera una cadena, hace falta recuperar el valor retornado por la consulta. esto es posible con [fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) de la siguiente forma.

```
if ($resultado =mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT sum(stock) as suma FROM  principal")) {
    $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

    echo $row['suma'];
}
```