# convertir el resultado de un query SQL en una variable entera de PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Quiero almacenar el resultado de una consulta SQL en una variable de PHP pero como un entero, este es mi codigo:

```
$maxnroviaje=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(NROVIAJE) from viajes");
$nroviajenew=mysql_fetch_assoc($maxnroviaje);
```

y al hacer echo en esas dos variables:

```
<?php echo $maxnroviaje; ?>
<?php echo $nroviajenew; ?>
```

lo que me arroja es lo siguiente:

> Resource id #15
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\agente-nav-online\agregar-viaje.php on line 47 Array

Comment: Cambie el `select` a  `"SELECT MAX(NROVIAJE) as nroviajes from viajes" ` y luego haga  `echo $nroviajenew['nroviajes'];`  ya que la variable `$nroviajenew` es un `array` , debe acceder a su indice _(columnas del select)_ Igual la extensión está deprecated presta a ser victima de [Ataques de Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) , con la Extensión Mysqli [puede hacerse  parecido a esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139144/error-object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-string-al-intentar/139149#139149)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
$maxnroviaje=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(NROVIAJE) as maximo from viajes");
$nroviajenew=mysql_fetch_assoc($maxnroviaje);
$nroviajex=$nroviajenew["maximo"];
```

claro, basandome en las respuestas aquí colocadas.

Answer (score 0):

1.- **$maxnroviaje** es un arreglo porque es la información que retorna mysql de la consulta a nivel general.

2.- **$nroviajenew** también es un arreglo porque es el resultado de la conversión de la query hacia los campos solicitados.

Podrias probar hacer esto:

```
$maxnroviaje = $db->query("SELECT MAX(NROVIAJE) as cuenta from viajes");
$nroviajenew = $maxnroviaje->fetch_assoc();

echo $nroviajenew["cuenta"];
//otra alternativa para mostrar el resultado de un vector 
echo $nroviajenew->cuenta;
```

de esta manera si estarías mostrando el resultado que buscas.

Saludos

> NOTA: La librería mysql esta depreciada en PHP, debes utilizar mysqli o pdo para tus consultas, de esa manera evitaras que tu sistema falle a futuro.

Answer (score -1):

`$nroviajenew` es un arreglo, no es un solo valor. Puedes usar var_dump para que veas la estructura del arreglo.

Lo correcto en este caso es usar `$nroviajenew[0]`.

Comment: Marcos, me podrías dar un ejemplo de la sintaxis del var_dump? en que parte del código lo uso?