# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una suma en Mysql de las filas de una columna?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 4 filas en la tabla "productos" lo que deseo es sumar la columna "stock".

```
id  Nombre  precio  stock
1   Tijeras $5.00   35
2   casacas $55.00  55
3   jeans   $67.00  20
4   zapatos $45.00  15
```

Solo quiero sumar todos los valores de la columna stock.

Alguien me podría ayudar con esa consulta.

Comment: ¿Qué ha intentado? de momento [esta respuesta puede ayudarle en su cometido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/139149), claro está que deberá reemplazar  principal por productos.

Comment: Gracias Dev.Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te comento que para darle solución a tu pregunta; es del modo siguiente:

```
SELECT SUM(stock) as stock FROM productos;
```

Uso la función SUM, que por dentro de los paréntesis recibe el nombre de la columna que quieres sumar y le colocas un alias con AS.

De tal modo que obtienes la suma de esa columna

Saludos

Comment: Hola Alfredo Paz ahora lo voy a intentar a ver si me funciona.

Comment: por favor si te funciona puntúame la respuesta saludos

Comment: Claro Alfredo Paz por cierto porque total_stock debo crear una columna total_stock o? no seria asi -->

SELECT SUM(stock) as stock FROM productos;

Comment: No, solo se va a mostrar tu resultado final con una columna con ese nombre; pero no te preocupes es temporal y no debes agregar ninguna columna a tu tabla, dejala como esta eso solo aparecera al momento de la ejecución de la consulta

Comment: ya le hecho los cambios necesarios

Comment: Genial me funciona perfecto cuando realizo la consulta en Mysql y cuando paso a PHP solo me muestra 1, pero la consulta esta perfecta gracias brother ahora te doy tu punto.